# Shape tag "<shape></shape>" in draw.io. Where can I find any documentation?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Is there any place where I could find a documentation about the `<shape>` tag used in draw.io? I don't know nothing about it. Is it a kind of `<svg>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's documented in the [user manual](https://support.draw.io/display/DO/Editing+Shapes).